# Linux - LXDE -- setting default browser will not stick

Tags: linux, lxde

OS=Debian stretch, running LXDE

Clicking on URL links from within non-browser programs, such as pidgin or Thunderbird does not open the links. I discovered that the default browser is set to `thunderbird.desktop` ... very odd... don't ask me how that got set.

```
$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
thunderbird.desktop
```

Trying to set the default browser with xdg-settings does not work:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox-esr.desktop
$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
thunderbird.desktop
```

Interestingly update-alternatives --get-selections shows firefox-esr as the default browser.

```
$ update-alternatives --get-selections |grep browser
gnome-www-browser              auto     /usr/bin/firefox-esr
infobrowser                    auto     /usr/bin/info
www-browser                    auto     /usr/bin/w3m
x-www-browser                  auto     /usr/bin/firefox-esr
```

I also tried an entry in `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
text/html=firefox-esr.desktop;
```

Nothing is working. Any help appreciated.

Update:

These lines in `~/.config/mimeapps.list` were set to `thunderbird.desktop`. I changed them to `firefox-esr.desktop`, but still no change.

```
application/x-extension-htm=firefox-esr.desktop
application/x-extension-html=firefox-esr.desktop
application/x-extension-shtml=firefox-esr.desktop
application/xhtml+xml=firefox-esr.desktop
application/x-extension-xhtml=firefox-esr.desktop
application/x-extension-xht=firefox-esr.desktop
```

Update:

The command `xdg-mime query filetype index.html` comes back empty. In fact it comes back empty with other filetypes as well. This has to mean something. However mimetype works.

```
$ mimetype index.html 
index.html: text/html
```

---

### **[SOLVED]** as per Xen2050's answer

Here is a summary of what I did, in case others have a similar problem:

I had to find all ''mimeapps.list'' and ''defaults.list'' files:

```
locate  mimeapps.list
locate defaults.list
```

Then delete them...

```
rm ~/.config/mimeapps.list
...
```

Then run:

```
update-desktop-database
```

In my case I got an error message about a faulty mime-type with evince (sorry, can't remember the exact message). So i purged evince:

```
apt-get purge evince
apt-get purge thunderbird #just for good measure
```

Try again:

```
update-desktop-database
```

The problem was still not solved, so I went on to install ''exo-preferred-applications'', which in Debian is the package ''exo-utils''. Then reinstall thunderbird. I don't need evince so didn't reinstall it.

```
apt-get install exo-utils
apt-get install thunderbird
```

Then ran ''exo-preferred-applications''.  Firefox was not listed under "Web Browsers", so I chose ''other'' and pasted in ''firefox-esr.desktop''. Then ran:

```
update-desktop-database
```

Working!!!:

```
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
firefox-esr.desktop
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
firefox-esr.desktop
```

The original problem of clicking on links in non-browser applications is also now solved.

Comment: Hi @ajnabi please remove SOLVED from the title and question. Add an own answer instead, you can mark this answer as solution too.

Comment: removed SOLVED from title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI's *"Settings"* -> *"Preferred applications"* looks like it sets `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` also, perhaps differently and definitely with an easier interface, so try there.

- It looks like it runs `exo-preferred-applications`
- Might rely on the file `/usr/share/applications/exo-web-browser.desktop` (or corresponding file in `/usr/local/` or `~/.local`) containing `Exec=exo-open --launch WebBrowser %u`

Also try

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

Also, checking the default mimetypes command you were looking for was probably one of these:

```
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
```

If MIME types were changed, the command `[sudo] update-desktop-database` might help.

- More info on mimetypes & file associations: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored

Comment: I had already tried all your suggestions except the ''exo-preferred-applications'', which after doing some cleanup fixed the problem. I put the details of the steps I took in the original post for others who might be up against the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the desktop environment is LXDE.  Out of curiosity, I checked two of my other LXDE computers and they didn't have exo-utils installed either.

Answer (score 0):

Problem already known in Debian GNU/Linux 8 alias Jessie.
No matter whether you LXDE or Gnome. :-(

**Here ist the Evince error message:**

```
~$ sudo update-desktop-database
```

Error in file "/usr/share/applications/evince.desktop": 
"" is an invalid MIME type ("" does not contain a subtype)

I purged evince. Not needed, too...

**My System:**

```
~$ uname -a
```

Linux 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3 (2019-09-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: I've also just faced this problem, and solved it by overriding, as user root, `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` with the appropriate values for `x-sceheme-handler/http`, etc.

For some reason it seems that this file takes precedence over any local, user-writable files.